# how to remove all html tag and concatenate text

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm using BeautifulSoup.

```
review =page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"content"})
```

below is the output of my review

```
 review    = [<div class="content">
    <div class="text show-more__control">AAAAA.</div>
    <div class="actions text-muted">
                        3 out of 8 found this helpful.
                            <span>
                                Was this review helpful? <a href="/registration/signin?ref_=urv"> Sign in</a> to vote.
                            </span>
    <br/>
    <a href="/review/rw1429145/?ref_=tt_urv">Permalink</a>
    </div>
    </div>, <div class="content">
    <div class="text show-more__control">BBBBB.</div>
    <div class="actions text-muted">
                        1 out of 2 found this helpful.
                            <span>
                                Was this review helpful? <a href="/registration/signin?ref_=urv"> Sign in</a> to vote.
                            </span>
    <br/>
    <a href="/review/rw2895175/?ref_=tt_urv">Permalink</a>
    </div>
    </div>]
```

i want it change to raw text like this.

```
AAAAA.BBBBB.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `text` on `div` with class `show-more__control`.

```
divs=page_soup.find_all('div',class_="show-more__control")
texts=[x.text for x in divs]
print(''.join(texts))
```

If `show_more__control` is present elsewhere you can use

```
contents=page_soup.find_all('div',class_="content")
texts=[x.find('div',class_='show-more__control').text for x in contents]
print(''.join(texts))
```

**Edit**: Edited answer to reflect change in your question

Original Question's html with answer

```
html="""
<div class="content">
<div class="text show-more__control">AAAAA.<br/><br/>Ted's Evaluation -- 1 of 3: You can find something better to do with this part of your life.</div>
<div class="actions text-muted">
                    3 out of 8 found this helpful.
                        <span>
                            Was this review helpful? <a href="/registration/signin?ref_=urv"> Sign in</a> to vote.
                        </span>
<br/>
<a href="/review/rw1429145/?ref_=tt_urv">Permalink</a>
</div>
</div>, <div class="content">
<div class="text show-more__control">BBBBB.</div>
<div class="actions text-muted">
                    1 out of 2 found this helpful.
                        <span>
                            Was this review helpful? <a href="/registration/signin?ref_=urv"> Sign in</a> to vote.
                        </span>
<br/>
<a href="/review/rw2895175/?ref_=tt_urv">Permalink</a>
</div>
</div>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
divs=soup.find_all('div',class_="show-more__control")
texts=[x.contents[0] for x in divs]
print(''.join(texts))
```

Output:

```
AAAAA.BBBBB.
```

Just using the `text` attribute in this case would have given the output

```
AAAAA.Ted's Evaluation -- 1 of 3: You can find something better to do with this part of your life.BBBBB.
```